Interpretation of return as a random variable in TRPO paper
I wanted to try to align some formulation from the TRPO paper (especially the last equation) with a book that I am using to learn about RL Mathematics of Reinforcement Learning, I would like to write it down more rigoruosly interpreting reward as a random variable. This is the part of the TRPO paper that I am looking at:

I have the following two formulas, that I think I would need to use to rewrite $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \gamma^t R_{t+1}\right] = \sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}} d(s)\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \gamma^t R_{t+1}|S_0 = s\right]$
, but I am not sure how I can rewrite the expected return in terms of those to make some progress:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} [R_{t+1}|S_0 = s_0] &= \sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}} \mathbb{E} [R_{t+1}|S_t = s, S_0 = s_0] p^{(t)}(s|s_0) \\
&= \sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}} \mathbb{E} [R_{t+1}|S_t = s] p^{(t)}(s|s_0) \\
&= \sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}} r_\pi(s)p^{(t)}(s|s_0),
\end{align*}
where $p^{(t)}(s|s_0)$ denotes the probability of transitioning from $s_0$ to  $s$ using exactly $t$ step and
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[R_{t+1}|S_t = s] &= \sum_{a\in\mathcal{A}} \pi(a|s)\mathbb{E}[R_{t+1}|S_t = s, A_t = a] \\
&= \sum_{a\in\mathcal{A}} \pi(a|s) \sum_{r\in\mathcal{R}} p(r|s,a)r.
\end{align*}
Any idea?
